# Pandas keep column after multiple aggregations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do multiple aggragations over a pandas dataframe, the problem is that I want to keep the column over I aggregate

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Y' : [1, 4, 3, 2]})
df3.groupby('X', as_index=False).agg('sum')

   X  Y
0  A  4
1  B  6
```

That's good but what I want is multiple aggregations like this

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Y' : [1, 4, 3, 2]})
df3.groupby('X', as_index=False).agg(['sum', 'mean'])
```

It gives me

```
    Y     
    sum mean
X         
A   4    2
B   6    3
```

But I want this

```
    X   Y     
        sum mean

0   A   4   2
1   B   6   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move `X` from the index to a column use `reset_index`:

```
In [4]: df3 = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], 'Y' : [1, 4, 3, 2]})

In [5]: df3.groupby('X', as_index=False).agg(['sum', 'mean']).reset_index()
Out[5]: 
   X   Y     
     sum mean
0  A   4    2
1  B   6    3
```